# Phonegap Build + iOS: media plugin does not work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

The Cordova media plugin doesn't work on my Phonegap **BUILD** app. I tried all the other SO questions, none of the answers helped. Audio will not play. Please review my configurations to see if something can be changed for it to work. I played around with changing the Phonegap version and media plugin version to no avail.

BTW, this used to work one year ago when I last deployed on a previous version of Phonegap build. I now had to change the plugins so they are all from the NPM source instead of Phonegap Build's own plugin repository. This broke the audio on iOS, but loading a previous version of the Media plugin didn't help. Perhaps there is a version that works which I didn't find.

config.xml

```
...
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.3.2" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="3.0.1" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="2.2.3" />


<access origin="http://*/*" />
<access origin="https://*/*" /> 
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
...
```

Media plugin is used as follows:

```
media = new Media(url, function(){/*success*/}, function(){/*fail*/});
media.play(); // doesn't play on iOS, does play on Android
media.getCurrentPosition(... //doesn't work on iOS either
```

No javascript errors are in the console.

Here is an example of a url that is being used:

https://streamingampmusicireland.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/MUSIC/pgh__/00003/pgh__-00003-00018-44s112.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJKA4UTQ3AL4FXUBQ&Expires=1499956327&Signature=MvpcTg1WBE4nt3sOjTRNTbr2Hg8%3D&x-amz-security-token=FQoDYXdzEL%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaDOPF2YpDNg5OLEGbjiL2AT3026p4YgRiIeZcaRnLg4kkB%2BnHN6T4Chfz9iwEPfMb1gd0WgfgGYClnevPmDHIPUuh9x7AY66CnXZZ6RgfUW1Nme3wExntY%2FOkiK6a9%2B7%2F1mijpppSoI2NHzrUiod%2F9mJTi%2FJQQwPIktWZPIMMXDlRNj0Gx4Lp%2Fi8ND6T%2BVaIrYGZntjDsUL%2Bp41ITeqr4hs6rQuSXgWEx47JXrpB%2FQSJ75Dz01qqo8hjsnj6B0rPvpAZrANuLDC2n5o1wZehJYb0456kHgZZSLQbYJ%2FKIVBoYoEqGnsOMec%2F6OzcHUwXKiaB8hGYarhJhHCiARcIESBOG6fvQASil3ZjLBQ%3D%3D

Comment: Where is the file located, what URL are you using for the media file and what is the format of the file?

Comment: MP3 files, they are externally loaded from an Amazon bucket using the full https:// url. I will update the answer with an example url, I cannot past it here because it is too long